# Plotly.js Adding markers adds padding to x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly

Is there a way to prevent Plotly from changing the padding on the x-axis when adding markers to a line chart.
Please see the two snippets below. The only difference is line 24 where `'lines'` is changed to `'lines+markers'`.

First snippet without markers:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <script>
    var layout = {
      xaxis: {
        showticklabels: true,
        tickmode: 'auto',
        nticks: 15,
        tickangle: 45,
        rangemode: 'tozero',
      },
    };

    var trace1 = {
      x: ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8'],
      y: [10, 15, 13, 17, 10, 15, 13, 17],
      type: 'scatter',
      mode: 'lines',
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
  </script>
</body>
```

Second snippet with markers:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <script>
    var layout = {
      xaxis: {
        showticklabels: true,
        tickmode: 'auto',
        nticks: 15,
        tickangle: 45,
        rangemode: 'tozero',
      },
    };

    var trace1 = {
      x: ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8'],
      y: [10, 15, 13, 17, 10, 15, 13, 17],
      type: 'scatter',
      mode: 'lines+markers',
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
  </script>
</body>
```

[image: Padding difference]

Comment: Can you be more specific? On chrome (Windows/Mac/Linux) the padding on the x axes are the same. I even saved both as images and overlaid them - other than the dots at the apexes the two are identical. Which browser / os do you see a difference? Can you post a screen grab of it?

Comment: I've added a screenshot that shows the difference. I'm on Chrome (Windows).

Comment: got you, think I have a decent answer for you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the solution I found was to set `autorange` to `false` **AND** specify the x-axis `range`. See: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range

Fixed example:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <script>
    var layout = {
      xaxis: {
        showticklabels: true,
        tickmode: 'auto',
        nticks: 15,
        tickangle: 45,
        rangemode: 'tozero',
        range: [0, 7]
      },
    };

    var trace1 = {
      x: ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8'],
      y: [10, 15, 13, 17, 10, 15, 13, 17],
      type: 'scatter',
      mode: 'lines+markers',
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that when `range` is provided, `autorange` is automagically set to `False`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a little bit confusing as it is actually the y-axis that is off.
Anyhow this can be resolved by setting the `yaxis` to  `showgrid: false` then offsetting the `yaxislayer-above` to relocate the labels.

This could be done in css, as I have, or in Javascript.

I might not have it pixel identical here (set at 102px) but you should get the idea.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .yaxislayer-above {
     transform: translate(102px,100px);
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
  <script>
    var layout = {
      yaxis: {
        showgrid: false,
      },
      xaxis: {
        showticklabels: true,
        tickmode: 'auto',
        nticks: 15,
        tickangle: 45,
        rangemode: 'tozero',
      },
    };

    var trace1 = {
      x: ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8'],
      y: [10, 15, 13, 17, 10, 15, 13, 17],
      type: 'scatter',
      mode: 'lines+markers',
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Definitely a great answer. However, it's really still doing the same thing and changing the x-axis. Now we are just moving the y-axis so it's not as obvious. https://imgur.com/a/pi49e In this toy example it doesn't make much of a difference - but in my real use case with a more complex it's very obvious. See this: https://imgur.com/a/fhFuQ

Comment: Sounds great. Looking forward to seeing the answer. Thanks!

Comment: just a bump. Would love to see your suggestion.

Comment: @Wessi - hmm still playing with it - what I had in mind was a bit contrived...just keep the question open and I will have a play with it when I get a chance for sure. The odd thing is *why* they are scaled differently - there is no real reason, going to have a look through the plotlyjs source and get to the bottom of it...

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `range` works but I noticed that   when you autoscale the axes with a modebar button or a mouse double-click, the padding is re-added automatically (at least in python). So I rather use [autorangeoptions_maxallowed](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-autorangeoptions-maxallowed) and [autorangeoptions_minallowed](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-autorangeoptions-minallowed) with upper and lower bounds of the range I want.